# Postman Parsing CSV to compare to environment variable not equals

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing, postman

I am attempting to parse a return .csv dataset and compare each row of the CSV data to a postman environment variable I already have set.

The environment variable is being retrieved properly, as well as the data I want from each row of the CSV, but, when comparing the two values to each other - there is no match found - this is strange as when I manually search for the value in Postman - I can find the 7 results I am expecting to find

This is currently setup as a Test Script after receiving the CSV data. I don't need to actually test the data, but rather use the results for a subsequent call.

```
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync'),
parsedBody = parse(responseBody, {columns: ["id", "dataToCompare"], trim: true});

var enviromentData = pm.environment.get("dataToCompare");

parsedBody.forEach(function(row) {

    var currentData = row.dataToCompare;
    var currentId = row.id;

    if (currentData == enviromentData) {
        //This Never Runs!!!
        console.log("match");
        //console.log(currentId);
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the datatype of the of those variables in the if statement? Should it also be ===? Would you be able to give an example of the csv file and the environment variables?

Comment: @DannyDainton thanks for that - turns out the environment variables need to be converted to string via toString(). Good call out on the === as well